# Style PHP using echo Issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress, user-profile

Using this code on my WP site and need help styling the echo lines of code;

```
              `<?php 
                if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                    if ( ($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) {
                        echo '' . esc_html( $current_user->display_name );
                        echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 38 );
                    }
                    }
                ?>`
```

Would like to use CSS classes, but when I try the below code it doesn't work;

```
echo '<p class="CSS Style">' . ($current_user->display_name ) '</p>';
```

Thanks to anyone that can help.  Probably pretty simple to most developers.

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: Please explain how it doesn't work, what is the output vs the expected output

Answer (score 1):

I try run your code, i think you are missing the ' . ' before `</p>`.

`echo '<p class="CSS Style">' . ($current_user->display_name ) . '</p>';`

Comment: They _are_ missing a `.` before `</p>` so nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can also do something like this if you want write a standalone P tag outside the PHP logic.

```
<?php 
     if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( ($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) { ?>

            <p class="username"><?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?></p>

<?php
        echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 38 );

        }
     }
?>
```

Otherwise, you can only add a dot before P closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this line of code**

```
echo '<p class="CSS Style">' . ($current_user->display_name ).'</p>';
```

Your forgot to give period(.);